# Call a program written in python in a program written in Ocaml

Tags: python, ocaml

I wanted to ask if you could call in a program written in Ocaml a program written in python , and if the answer is yes how do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What exactly are you intending to do?  Do you want to run it and forget about it?  Then do a fork/exec.  Do you want run it and wait until it's finished but otherwise do nothing?  Then use `Sys.command`.  Do you want to read/write to it?  Then uses `Unix.open_process*` (or `Unix.create_process*`).

For example, if I want to run `ls` and print out the results, I can do this:

```
let ls = Unix.open_process_in "ls"
try
  while true do
    Printf.printf "%s\n" (input_line ls)
  done
with End_of_file -> ()
Unix.close_process_in ls
```

Comment: I call the program in python within of the program ocaml and use the output within this program.

Comment: Then use open_process or create_process.  You can find some documentation here: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "fork/exec"?

Answer (score 2):

Don't have any real life experience with this, but this sounds interesting (from the [Integrating Python with other languages wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages)):

*[Pycaml](http://pycaml.sourceforge.net/): write Python extension modules in OCaml (instead of C), and use Python code and native libraries from OCaml programs.*

Answer (score 2):

You can execute commands using `Sys.command`, so you can just do `Sys.command "python foo.py"`, assuming python is in your path and foo.py is in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

If your program is an executable (otherwise you would compile it ;) ) you can use the Unix module as you use it in C, for example :

```
let program = "path_to_python_program_exe" in

match Unix.fork () with
    | 0 -> (try
          Unix.execvp program [|program; "any_more_args_here"|]
       with
          _ -> printf "%s" "error while execv\n"; exit (-1))
    | -1 -> printf "%s" "error accured on fork\n"
    | _ -> ignore (wait ()); printf "%s" "parent exit...\n"
```

When you compile, you use the unix.cma for the compiler: `ocamlc unix.cma you_ml.ml`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use the [Shell library](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview%3abatteries-beta1/html/api/Shell.html).

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your exact requirements, but you can use pythons os.system() to execute an program in the same way you would call it from the command line. That should be a good starting point.

Comment: That's the opposite thing - calling a ocaml program from a python program. Not what was asked at all. Also, don't use `os.system()` since the `subprocess` module is preferable.